# Use Uri.encode implementation in Java library

Tags: java, android

I am implementing a Java library. In the library, I am required to use Java equivalent of Android's Uri.encode() method. Though initially I thought of using something like :

```
encodedString = URLEncoder.encode(originalString, "UTF-8")
      .replaceAll("\\+", "%20")
      .replaceAll("\\%21", "!")
      .replaceAll("\\%27", "'")
      .replaceAll("\\%28", "(")
      .replaceAll("\\%29", ")")
      .replaceAll("\\%7E", "~")
```

But I observed that Android's implementation of Uri.encode() only depends on StringBuilder class (and hence can be copy-pasted with minor changes in naming) to my library. What things would I need to take care of before I use that piece of code.

Comment: I am mostly interested in the licensing aspects.. Can I directly copy-paste Android SDK code in my library or would I need to add some comments or some file?

Comment: Why am I being downvoted for this question?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the string before returning it:

```
return new StringBuilder(encodedString);
```

Or use [`StringBuilde.replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#replace(int,%20int,%20java.lang.String)) method (which is faster but you will only nothe the difference if you use it inside a wide loop):

```
StringBuilder encodedString = new StringBuilder();
encodedString = URLEncoder.encode(originalString, "UTF-8")
  .replace(0, originalString.length(), "\\+", "%20")
  .replace(0, originalString.length(), "\\%21", "!")
  .replace(0, originalString.length(), "\\%27", "'")
  .replace(0, originalString.length(), "\\%28", "(")
  .replace(0, originalString.length(), "\\%29", ")")
  .replace(0, originalString.length(), "\\%7E", "~");
```

Comment: I am not interested in converting the String to builder but rather interested in using Android's implementation of Uri.encode